# Magento2 reuse add to cart form template

Tags: forms, cart, code-reuse, magento2

Is it possible to reuse somehow magentos 2 `add to cart form` in a custom module? I have in tab all child products of current product and I want to allow customers to add to cart products so thats how looks my code at this status

```
<?php
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    $variants = $block->getVariants($currentProduct);
    if($variants) { ?>
        <ul id="product-variants">
        <?php foreach ($variants as $_product) : ?>
          <li>
              <form>
                  <?php echo  $_product->getName(); ?>
                  SKU: <?php echo  $_product->getSku(); ?>
                  Brutto: <?php echo  $_product->getPrice(); ?>

                  <input type="text" placeholder="Stück">
                  <button>Add to cart</button>

              </form>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php };
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add button in custom phtml file as follow, I have done this in custom module

In your block file

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
<?php
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
    }

public function getProductCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
   $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    return $collection;
}
public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
?>
```

get productlist in view file

```
<?php 
const PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL = 'r64';
const PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED = 'uenc';
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
$_productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getName()?>
    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <?php $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                    class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
            </button>
    </form>
<?php endforeach;?>
```